# Swift Notifications on Test Flight not working

Tags: xcode, swift, notifications, push

I have spent the last day or two pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I am able to send push notifications in development on an Xcode build just fine, but when uploading to test flight nothing comes through.

I have read all the documentation, re-generated all my certificates and spent hours on forums but I'm still at a loss. I'm pretty new to Xcode so if someone could have a look over I would be eternally grateful!

- Member Centre Certificates

[image: Member centre]
 - No App wild card used. Push notifications enabled for both Development and Distribution - with all SSL certificates generated and uploaded.

[image]

[image]

- Distribution Provisioning profile has push notifications enabled as service:

[image]

- Code Signing set to distribution on both project and target:

[image]

[image]

I have uploaded that build to test flight for internal testing. When I try to send a push it says the data is sent successfully to the apple server, but no push is received on the device:

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the device token?